# Is there a way to ignore the superclass properties in Snake yaml

Tags: parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

I tried setting the representer as follows

```
Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);
```

But it still fails on some super class property which i don't have any control over.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `TypeDescription` to tell SnakeYAML it should skip super class properties:

```
final td = new TypeDescription(MyClass.class);
td.setExcludes("property1", "property2" /* ... */);
representer.addTypeDescription(td);
```

`MyClass` is the child class.